# Code block in python in order to free memory

Tags: python, memory, scopes

Pretty simple question:
I have some code to show some graphs, and it prepares data for the graphs, and I don't want to waste memory (limited)... is there a way to have a "local scope" so when we get to the end, everything inside is freed?

I come from C++ where you can define code inside `{ ... }` so at the end everything is freed, and you don't have to care about anything

Anything like that in python?

The only thing I can think of is:

```
def tmp():
   ... code ...

tmp()
```

but is very ugly, and for sure I don't want to list all the `del x` at the end

Comment: Python's scoping rules are not as sophisticated as C.  Function scope, as you have it there, is the right way.

Comment: @TimRoberts yeah I can see, but my experience in python is way less than in C++, so I was asking because I might don't know some trick

Answer (score 2):

If anything holds a reference to your object, it cannot be freed. By default, anything at the global scope is going to be held in the global namespace (`globals()`), and as far as the interpreter knows, the very next line of source code *could* reference it (or, another module could import it from this current module), so globals cannot be implicitly freed, ever.

This forces your hand to either explicitly delete references to objects with `del`, or to put them within the local scope of a function. This may seem ugly, but if you follow the philosophy that a function should do one thing and one thing well (thanks Unix!), you will already segment your code into functions already. On the one-off exceptions where you allocate a lot of memory early on in your function, and no longer need it midway through, you can `del` the reference to it.

I know this isn't the answer you want to hear, but its the reality of Python. You *could* accomplish something similar by nesting function `def`s or `class`s inside, but this is kinda hacky (or in the `class` case, which wouldn't require calling/instantiating, **extremely** hacky).

I will also mention, there is a `gc` built in module for interacting with the garbage collector. Here, you can trigger an immediate garbage collection (otherwise python will eventually get around to collecting the things you `del` refs to), as well as inspect how many references a given object has.

If you're curious where the allocations are happening, you can also use the built in `tracemalloc` module to trace said allocations.

Comment: *"If anything holds a reference to your object, it cannot be freed."* - Unless for example that's the only reference and your object holds the only reference to that anything.

Comment: @KellyBundy that's a fair point-  Python's garbage collection is smart enough to handle cyclic references, so I guess I overgeneralized there.

Comment: I'm not asking how a garbage collector works, but if there are more "clear" ways to do that... btw tnk u

Answer (score 1):

Mechanism that handles freeing memory in Python is called "Garbage Collector" and it means there's no reason to use `del` in overwhelming majority of Python code.

When programming in Python, you are "not supposed" to care about such low level things as allocating and freeing memory for your variables.

That being said, putting your code into functions (although preferrably called something clearer than `tmp()`) is most definitely a good idea as it will make your code much more readable and "Pythonic"

Answer (score 1):

Coming from C++ and already stumbled to one of the main diferences (drawbacks) of python and this is memory management.Python Garbage Collector will delete all the objects that will fall out of scope.Freeing up memory of objects althought doesnt guarantee that this memory will return actually to the system but instead a rather big portion will be kept reserved by the python programm even if not used.If you face a memory problem and you want to free your memory back to the system the only safe method is to run the memory intensive function into a seperate process.Every process in python have its own interpreter and any memory consumed by this process will return to the system when the process exits.

Comment: I'm not asking how a garbage collector works, but if there are more "clear" ways to do that... btw, tnk u

Comment: I don't think there is a more elegand way except from forking a separate process that may be expensive